# create a comma separated list containing the names of all variables starting with a prefix

Tags: bash, qsub

I am currently trying to write a Bash script that can submit multiple jobs to an SGE QSUB cluster and submit some environmental variables to each job.

In order to pass variables to each job, I need to list all the variables that I want to pass as a single string (in the form of a comma separated list such as `'var1={var1},var2={var2}'`).

I am wondering how to automate this process. Specifically, I would like to write a script that does the following:

1) collect the names of all variables that begin with a certain prefix
2) strip the prefix from those names
3) create a comma-separated list

As an example, consider the following script (where the prefix is `jobvar`):

```
jobvar_my_vector=(0.1 2.00 3.00)
jobvar_my_string="hello"
other_variable="yesyesyes"
```

Here the command would basically produce a variable `list_of_variables` which would be a string like:
`"my_string=${my_string},my_vector=${my_vector}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set` command in POSIX mode to list all variable. Then use a pipe to awk to parse the variable and get your desired output.

```
s=$(set -o posix; set | awk -F '(jobvar_|=)' '/^jobvar_/{printf "%s=${%s},", $2, $2}')
echo "$s"
my_string=${my_string},my_vector=${my_vector},
```

In BASH you can also use `compgen -v` to get all variables:

```
s=$(compgen -v | awk -F '(jobvar_|=)' '/^jobvar_/{printf "%s=${%s},", $2, $2}')
echo "$s"
my_string=${my_string},my_vector=${my_vector},
```

Comment: Why not just use the parameter substitution that returns all variables with a given prefix instead?

Comment: Thanks! Both work solutions great. I added an extra line `s="${s%?}"` in order to remove the last ',' at the end of the string.